# The function of parentheses (round brackets) in R

Tags: r, data.table, parentheses

How does R interpret parentheses? Like most other programming languages these are built-in operators, and I normally use them without thinking.

However, I came across this example. Let's say we have a `data.table` in R, and  I would like to apply a function on it's columns. Then I might write:

```
dt <- data.table(my_data)
important_cols <- c("col1", "col2", "col5")
dt[, (important_cols) := lapply(.SD, my_func), .SDcols = important_cols]
```

Obviously I can't neglect the parentheses:

```
dt[, important_cols := lapply(.SD, my_func), .SDcols = important_cols]
```

as that would introduce a new object called `important_cols` to my `data.table`, instead of modifying my existing columns in place.

My question is, why does putting ( ) around the vector "expand" it?

This question can probably better phrased and titled. But then I would have probably found the answer by Googling if I knew the terminology to employ while asking it, hence I'm here.

While we're on that topic, if someone could point out the differences between [ ], { }, etc., and how they should be used, that would be appreciated too :)

Comment: Open parentheses indicate the beginning of an argument list and the token to the left of the open-paren should be a function name. If there is no token to the left of the open-paren it is an implicit call to `eval`. You should not use data.table syntax to learn R syntax. It's a really kewl package but the syntax is completely different inside `[.data.table`

Comment: You'll find a lot of information on the help for `[` using `?"["`. There's also some (but not much) information on `?"{"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A special feature of R (compared to e.g. C++) is that the various parentheses are actually functions. What this means is that `(a)` and `a` are different expressions. The second is just `a`, while the first is the *function* `(` called with an argument `a`. Here are a few expressions trees for you to compare:

```
as.list(substitute( a ))
#[[1]]
#a

as.list(substitute( (a) ))
#[[1]]
#`(`
#
#[[2]]
#a

as.list(substitute( sqrt(a) ))
#[[1]]
#sqrt
#
#[[2]]
#a
```

Notice how similar the last trees are - in one the function is `sqrt`, in the other it's `"("`. In most places in R, the `"("` function doesn't do anything, it just returns the same expression, but in the particular case of `data.table`, it is "overridden" (in quotes because that's not exactly how it's done, but in spirit it is) to do a variety of useful operations.

And here's one more demo to hopefully cement the point:

```
`(` = function(x) x*x
2
#[1] 2
(2)
#[1] 4
((2))
#[1] 16
```